# Shopware 6.5 Icon Changes

Tags: shopware, shopware6

According to the documentation, icon names changed in Shopware 6.5.
A mapping should be found here `src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/base/sw-icon/legacy-icon-mapping.js`.

The problem is, this file does not exist. Not in Shopware 6.5 RC4, nor in the latest 6.4.20.0.

So, where is it? I have to rename a couple of icons and need the new names.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when the file was removed from the repository, it should have stayed there at least for the 6.4 versions. You can find the mapping here: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4.14.0/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/app/component/base/sw-icon/legacy-icon-mapping.js

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this fell under the table indeed. You can find a searchable overview of the new meteor icon kit [here](https://shopware.github.io/meteor-icon-kit/). Hope this helps for now. A mapping of old to new icons would be handy nonetheless. If I find anything I'll update this answer.

Edit: Well, speak of the devil.